# How to handle the scenario "access_token changes when user changes facebook password"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am able to see from the following link that, if password change, access_token will get invalidated.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

So, how to identify when user change his/her password.

I did not see anything about this in the graph api documentation.

Please help me regarding this.

Thanks,
Gopal.

Answer (score 2):

When access_token is invalidated due to password change, you can no longer make Graph API calls, i.e. Graph API returns an error. You can recognize this error and set a flag in user profile which triggers a notification "Hi Gopal, you have to reconnect your account with FB. To do so, click [here]", where [here] points to the regular FB oauth url (i.e. https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize).

EDIT 14/05/2011: Facebook just released blog entry on this topic: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500

Comment: @Tomasz If I am right, this should be handled in the catch part of the exception handling. What error(string) should I exactly look for?

Comment: @Ashfame: What exactly do you mean - could you elaborate?

Comment: @Tomasz Like you pointed we can handle the scenario by checking the error returned by Graph API. What the error should be? By checking error type & error message, right? What the strings should be for which our check returns true? Like `OAuthException` and `Invalid OAuth access token.` or something else? And how reliable this method is?

Comment: @Ashfame: Like you say, OAuthException is raised with detailed reason in `exc.message` field which says sth like "The user hasn't authorized the application" - but check yourself the exact spelling.

Comment: Hmm.. I will do with an account and checking the string it returns, thanks :) Upvoted!

Comment: Facebook has just made released tutorial on what you've asked :-) I've pasted the link in my answer.