# Does facebook notify to an app when app user changes his/her password?

Tags: facebook

Does facebook notify to an app when app user changes his/her password?

I found some related post [How to handle the scenario "access_token changes when user changes facebook password"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217003/how-to-handle-the-scenario-access-token-changes-when-user-changes-facebook-pass).

But what I want to know is instead of knowing due to error messages, Does facebook makes notification to an app as soon as user changes his/her password?

Something similar to deregistration as Facebook indeed makes notification when user deregisters an app.

I can't find related info on facebook developers site.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no.. they do not notify you of a password change. Error handling is the correct way to deal with this issue.

Comment: yah. I think this is the only way. Thanks :)